# Precision, recall and f1 scores discrepancies

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, knn

Why the results from precision, recall and f1 scores functions are different compared to when I calculate it? The accuracy score is the same though

```
cm = confusion_matrix(Y_test, y_pred)
cm
array([[94, 13],
       [16, 31]], dtype=int64)


cmtrain = [item for sublist in cm for item in sublist]
TP = cmtrain[0]
FP = cmtrain[1]
FN = cmtrain[2]
TN = cmtrain[3]

precision = TP/(TP + FP)
recall = TP/(TP + FN)
accuracy = (TP + TN) / (TP + TN + FP + FN)
f1 = (2*(precision * 0.75)) / (precision + 0.75)
print(accuracy,recall, precision,f1)

0.81, 0.85, 0.88, 0.81
```

vs

```
accuracyscore = accuracy_score(Y_test, y_pred)
precisionscore = precision_score(Y_test, y_pred)
recallscore = recall_score(Y_test, y_pred)
f1score = f1_score(Y_test, y_pred)

print(accuracyscore, recallscore, precisionscore,f1score)

0.81 0.65 0.70 0.68
```